# Codeigniter4 form validation

Tags: validation, codeigniter-4, codeigniter-form-validation

I'm porting my application from CI3 to CI4.

Having issues with the form validation. My goal is to validate the input only if the form is submitted. In **Codeigniter 3** a could do:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

And then it my view, I could display my errors:

```
echo validation_errors();
```

or display an error individually:

```
echo form_error('username');
```

All the errors would be displayed if the form was submitted. When I visit the page for the first time, no errors are shown.

Now in **Codeigniter 4**:

My controller is set up like this:

```
$validation =  \Config\Services::validation();

$validation->setRule('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[6]');
if ($validation->withRequest($this->request)->run()) {
    $username = $this->request->getVar('username');
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

The validation is working, but the errors are displayed always. Even when the form is not submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are only validating upon a 'post' request.
You can utilize `$this->request->getMethod()` inside a controller to check what type of request it is.

You can do something like this:

```php
if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post')
{
  // Validation
}
```